# Switch back from Chromecast to TV Trasmissions

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

How can i switch back to TV ( starting from a Google Cast with Chromecast ) when cast stop?

Switching from TV trasmissions to Cast is very simple. I'm not able to switch back from Cast to TV trasmissions when the cast finish.

How can i implement this feature?

Comment: what do you mean by "TV Transmissions"  is this for a google TV? vs. a google tablet/phone?

Comment: by "TV Trasmissions" i mean something which is not cast. So it could be TV Series on Cable TV.

Comment: From what you describe it seems casting to the Chromecast is signalling to the TV that it should change input source. For example my TV has multiple sources - DTV, HDMI-1, HDMI-2, EXT-1 (SCART), EXT-2 (SCART) etc etc. If a new source goes "live" the TV will switch to it but stopping  that source or putting it into standby doesn't necessarily mean my TV will revert to the previous source - I have to use the TV remote. Even if you can put the CHromecast to 'sleep' it doesn't mean the TV will switch back to where it was previously - that will depend on the TV model's behaviour.

Comment: +1, switching back to a certain hdmi channel sounds like it would be tough to do but not impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible to do right now. The control of the TV happens through HDMI-CEC, something which is handled by the firmware on the Chromecast and isn't exposed to either the sender or the receiver APIs. Lots of requests have been made to add such a feature to the SDK, but nothing yet exists.